# Include nested collections to firebase.profile

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I'm currently working on a React / Redux / Firebase application.

In my Firebase **Cloud Firestore** I store user data, dynamically created after creating an Auth user.

In my `index.js` I use `useFirestoreForProfile: true` to get the corresponding user data to show up in `firebase.profile`

**index.js**

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(
            thunk.withExtraArgument({
                getFirebase, // Firebase
                getFirestore // Cloud Database
            })
        ),
        reduxFirestore(fbInit),
        reactReduxFirebase(fbInit, {
            useFirestoreForProfile: true, // Sync user data to firebase.profile
            userProfile: 'users', // Tell Redux Firebase where our users are stored
            attachAuthIsReady: true // Enable firebase initializing before DOM rendering
        })
    )
);
```

My authentication action:

**/store/actions/authActions.js**

```
export const signIn = (credentials) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase}) => {
        const firebase = getFirebase();

        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            credentials.email,
            credentials.password
        ).then(() => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS'
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'LOGIN_ERROR',
                err
            })
        });
    }
}
```

The part of successful login in my authentication reducer:

**/store/reducers/authReducer.js**

```
  case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
      console.log('Login success');
      return {
         ...state,
         authError: null,
         authErrorDetails: null
      };
```

The way I map the state to the component props:

**/components/pages/Dashboard/index.jsx**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        records: state.firestore.ordered.records,
        tabs: state.firestore.ordered.tabs,
        auth: state.firebase.auth,
        profile: state.firebase.profile
    }
}
```

The current profile data looks like this:

### [image: Profile data]

Within the **user document** where those fields are set, I've created an **additional collection**.

The path would look as: `users -> (document id) -> tabs -> (document id) -> fields`

[image: Database structure]

Is there any way to include the tabs collections in **firebase.profile**

---

The final object should look something like the one I just **created manually** for displaying purposes:

[image: Desired structure]

Is there a way of achieving this? I really hope it's only a param missing or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I have solved the problem by creating an array within the user fields.

```
export const createTab = (tab) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
        // Make aync call to DB

        // Get userId (to know where to store the new tab)
        const userId = getState().firebase.auth.uid;
        // Get user tabSlots to decide how many tabs the user may have
        const userTabSlots = getState().firebase.profile.tabSlots;
        // Get current tabs (to not overwrite)
        const currentTabs = getState().firebase.profile.tabs;

        // Check if already exists
        let exists = currentTabs.map((ctab, i) => {
            if(ctab.title === tab.title){
                dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_TAB_ERROR_DUPLICATE', err: "Duplicate" });
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Check if the user can make new tabs dependent on the tier
        let canCreate = true;
        if(currentTabs.length === userTabSlots){
            dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_TAB_ERROR_LIMIT', err: "Tab limit reached" });
            canCreate = false;
        }

        // If it does not already exists and user can create new tabs
        if(!exists.includes(true) && canCreate){
            const firestore = getFirestore();
            firestore.collection('users').doc(userId).update({
                tabs: [
                    ...currentTabs,
                    {...tab, createdAt: new Date()} 
                ]
            }).then(() => {
                dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_TAB', tab });
            }).catch((err) => {
                dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_TAB_ERROR', err });
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any read operation to Firestore returns documents from a single collection (or if you use [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection_group)) from collections with the same name. There is no way to deeply query nested collections like you have in your data model. In your model you will need separate read operations for the documents from `users` and those from `tabs`.

Beyond that it's hard to say what specifically you will have to do, as I don't know what `useFirestoreForProfile` is and what the `profile` object you show represents.

Comment: When using `useFirestoreForProfile: true` as param in `reactReduxFirebase()` it will automatically get the corresponding data of the user you logged in and output it in the already existant firebase.profile object.